# XMPP "stream:error (conflict)" on login with (a)Smack

Tags: xmpp, smack, asmack

Currently i am working with xmpp/jabber chat for android.i just tried with Openfire and try to connect my jabber account.connection was successful.but i am not able to send any message.it shows some conflict error.please check the error log.give me a solution for this.

```
Initializing connection to server eworks port 5222
Connected: true
Creating entry for buddy 'testuser2' with name testuser2
Sending mesage 'Hello mate' to user testuser2@eworks
Buddy:testuser2 - Status:null
stream:error (conflict)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:306)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:76)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A XMPP `stream:error` because of a conflict means that there is already a connection with the same full JID (that is bare JID and resource part).

Most XMPP servers are able to handle conflicts by re-assigning a different resource once a conflict is detected. This behavior can be configured.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ShadowScripter I see an answer here. But the answer is incomplete: Conflicts only happen when you try to bind a JID resource that is already bound by the user and therefore connected. XMPP is designed to handle multiple connections from the same user (bare JID), but the resource has to be different then.

Comment: @Flow how to resolve the this issue as i am getting conflict error so how can i close the previously running connection with the same resource name and active the current one ? because if i will use different resource name then i can see lots of connection active with a same name

Comment: Hello , @Jithu P.S , i face same problem , you can help me if you done that...?

Comment: XMPP listener "connectionClosedOnError()" is called on previous running device when there is a conflict of the same client resource and it has StreamErrorException of conflict, with this we can close the previously running connection but the issue is, it's working only first time, this is issue i am facing right now. Anybody have idea about it?