# Connection closed with error in XMPP android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

The `XMPP` connection keeps getting `closed showing a conflict error`. What could be the reason for this behaviour? Please find the log.

```
12-02 18:20:58.105: W/XMPPConnection(20956): Connection closed with error
12-02 18:20:58.105: W/XMPPConnection(20956): stream:error (conflict)
12-02 18:20:58.105: W/XMPPConnection(20956):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:226)
12-02 18:20:58.105: W/XMPPConnection(20956):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:47)
12-02 18:20:58.105: W/XMPPConnection(20956):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:81)
12-02 18:20:58.115: D/SMACK(20956): Connection closed due to an exception (24)
```

Using `aSmack 8.4.0.5 jar.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMPP "stream:error (conflict)" on login with (a)Smack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077100/xmpp-streamerror-conflict-on-login-with-asmack)

Comment: @Flow I have followed that. But still it occurs. I am currently loggin in as follows :

connection.login(user_id, user_pw);

Comment: Also I get an exception as follows 

org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException

Answer (score 1):

A "conflict" stream error usually means that another client has connected with the same username and resource.  If you want both clients to be connected, you can use a random resource (or not specify any resource at all, in which case the server will generate one for you).